# Maven Project in Eclipse port connection refused

Tags: eclipse

How do I configure Eclipse to fix the error below:

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    ... 92 common frames omitted

Comment: What are you trying to do when you get this error?

Comment: I get this error when I run a Spring boot project for order tracking system